# Flutter - The argument type 'Iterable>' can't be assigned to type 'List'

Tags: list, flutter, scroll, flutter-getx

I want to get 5 more records in each api call and add them to the existing list.
However, the structure below gives an error. The error screenshot and the complete code structure is available below.

Explore page init

```
 @override
  void initState() {
        exploreController.fetchArticles(offsetCount: page);
    super.initState();
    _sc.addListener(() {
      if (_sc.position.pixels == _sc.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        page = page + 5;
        exploreController.fetchArticles(offsetCount: page);
      }
    });
  }
```

ExploreModel

```
List<ExploreModel> exploreModelFromJson(String str) => List<ExploreModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => ExploreModel.fromJson(x)));

String exploreModelToJson(List<ExploreModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

My api call

```
static Future<List<ExploreModel>> fetchArticleList(int offsetCount) async {
    var url = Uri.http(Config().baseUrl, Config().baseUrlPathGetArticles,
        {'offsetCount': '$offsetCount'});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return exploreModelFromJson(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and my controller

```
class ExploreController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var articleList = <ExploreModel>[].obs;
  var offsetCount = 0;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchArticles();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchArticles({int offsetCount = 0}) async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var articles = await ApiService.fetchArticleList(offsetCount);

      if (articles != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
          articleList.addAll(articles[i]);
        }
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[This is what i want to make](https://www.initpals.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Flutter_Lazy_Load.gif)

Comment: When you use "articles[i]" you're passing just a single item from the List as the parameter.  The .addAll() method expects the whole List as the parameter, and it will just take every item from the parameter List and add it into the list against which .addAll() is invoked.  So I guess you really just want to do "articleList.addAll(articles);" (of course, no need for the "for" loop either, in this case)   And p.s. your question title does not correctly match the actual error that you are receiving

Comment: Did my answer below not solve this problem and help you move forward?

Answer (score 4):

change this:

```
List<ExploreModel> exploreModelFromJson(String str) => List<ExploreModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => ExploreModel.fromJson(x)));
```

to this:

```
List<ExploreModel> exploreModelFromJson(String str) => List<ExploreModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => ExploreModel.fromJson(x)).toList()); //add the toList().
```

Comment: My friend thanks for answer. This asnwer solved my list type problem.

Comment: It solved THIS question's problem, you're most welcome.