# Flutter getx infinite scroll refreshing listview every end scroll

Tags: flutter, infinite-scroll, flutter-getx

I am trying to make infinite scroll in listview. I am fetching data from API. I am using getx. My listview always rebuild when scroll end.  I could not find where i did mistake.

[This is what i try to make](https://www.initpals.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Flutter_Lazy_Load.gif)

My model class;

```
List<ExploreModel> exploreModelFromJson(String str) => List<ExploreModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => ExploreModel.fromJson(x)).toList());

String exploreModelToJson(List<ExploreModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

My controller;

```
class ExploreController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var articleList = <ExploreModel>[].obs;
  var offsetCount = 0;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchArticles();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchArticles({int offsetCount = 0}) async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var articles = await ApiService.fetchArticleList(offsetCount);

      if (articles != null) {
        articleList.addAll(articles);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

My api call;

```
static Future<List<ExploreModel>> fetchArticleList(int offsetCount) async {
    var url = Uri.http(Config().baseUrl, Config().baseUrlPathGetArticles,
        {'offsetCount': '$offsetCount'});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return exploreModelFromJson(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

My view (StatefulWidget);

final ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
int offsetCount = 0;

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        offsetCount= offsetCount + 5;
        exploreController.fetchArticles(offsetCount: offsetCount);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
          onRefresh: () async {
            exploreController.fetchArticles();
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Obx(() {
                  if (exploreController.isLoading.value) {
                    return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                  }
                  return ListView.separated(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    itemCount: exploreController.articleList.length,
      }
...
```

Comment: I think you should change your listener condition to scrollController.position.offset >=
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent

Comment: You asked a question earlier today and got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66865671/13558035 but you didn't mark it as answered there or give any updates, yet you are using the code from that answer, and added `.toList()` to your code, apparently it's working.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad thanks for your reply but this code works good but when i reached at end of scroll, listview refrefshing.. I do not want this. I want this continue with new datas.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should fix your problem.

`itemCount: exploreController.articleList.length + 1`  and in the itemBuilder add a condition `if (index == exploreController.articleList.length) //show progress indicator or somthing else`
Or
you can do this way
Change your column to list view and do it this way

```
ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
            Obx(() {
              return ListView.separated(
                physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: exploreController.articleList.length,
                itemBuilder(context,index){
                //show your widget
               }
  })
  Obx(()=>exploreController.isLoading.value? 
  Container(height: 100, child: CupertinoActivityIndicator())
  : Container() )
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I implemented infinite scroll with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` instead, as `ScrollController` conditions are too cumbersome. It works like this:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
  if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
    onScrollListener();
  }

  return true;
}

void onScrollListener() {
  if (reachedEnd) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isPageLoading) {
    isPageLoading = true;
    Future.microtask(() async {
      final newItems = await getItemsUseCase.get(page: nextPage);
      if (newItems.length < pageSize) {
        reachedEnd= true;
      } else {
        nextPage++;
      }

      allItems.addAll(newItems);
      isPageLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I've added a complete [code example here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/infinite-scrolling-sliverlist-in-flutter-2236aa050a6c).